# bds with field in R returning error

Tags: programming, bloomberg

I am using Rblpapi and trying to query the following:

```
bds("FN1 Comdty","FUT_CHAIN", overrides = "CHAIN_DATE=20170101")
```

However, I am getting the following error:

```
 Error in bds_Impl(con, security, field, options, overrides, verbose, identity) : 
 Request overrides must be named.
```

Answer (score 1):

Overrides must have their value separately defined, try:

```
ovrd = c("CHAIN_DATE" = "20170101")
bds("FN1 Comdty","FUT_CHAIN", overrides = ovrd)
```